# Using AIP / MISP Labels without Office 365

Tags: azure, office365, document-classification

I'm in a daughter company of a corporation that uses Office 365, but our organisation doesn't.

I have an *.onmicrosoft.com acccount so I can receive and open AIP protected documents I get from the parent organisation and that works. I can also see the MISP_Label_*_(tag) entries in the document metadata.

I would like to translate those labels into the classification scheme we use in my organisation, automatically. Most importantly, I want to set those labels properly when I create a document that I send to the parent org.

- Can I rely on the UID being used in the tag names to be static, or could it change?
- Can I somehow get a list of all the labels and their UIDs used?
- Is there an official list of all the tags that AIP sets? I found several lists of those properties on different sites, typically 7 or 8, but nothing official.

Or is there even sample code somewhere that does that? I searched, found a few basic samples on how to use the MISP SDK, but nothing specific on how to set AIP labels.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitivity labels are added as custom/named properties to documents and emails. So, the exact way depends on the tools and solutions you develop.

> Can I rely on the UID being used in the tag names to be static, or could it change?

Yes, you can. They are defined and configured for the whole org.

> Can I somehow get a list of all the labels and their UIDs used?

Microsoft doesn't provide the full list of pre-defined sensitivity labels. But you can explore them on your own due to the fact they are stored like properties on documents or emails.

> Is there an official list of all the tags that AIP sets? I found several lists of those properties on different sites, typically 7 or 8, but nothing official.

Nope. Because they are configurable. See [Create and configure sensitivity labels and their policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-sensitivity-labels?view=o365-worldwide) for more information.

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I know that you configure the labels themselves, aka "public", "internal", "secret", etc. - I mean the MSIP_Label_*_xxx tags.

Comment: Such lists were not published anywhere.